# Viewing the web page inside EClipse

Tags: eclipse

So my first Web and JavaScript project with EClipse: I created a File->New General Project in EClipse and I added a New File to the project called myFirstPage.htm and I wrote some Hello World Javascript code in it, If I browse to the htm file on hard drive where the EClipse Workspace is saved, Yes I can open that page and shows my the hello world alert message. But if I click on the WebBrowser icon inside EClipse IDE it open a webpage that has no address in its address bar and well doesn't show the message either.  I think there are more setting I should do in EClipse to see this page, but what are they?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right Click your html file > open with > Web browser

Comment: oh thanks, it worked :) so for my learning: what was that WebBrowser toolbar icon I was clicking on? that has a different job?

Comment: Normal browser....bt it wont open up anything unless you type in the address and click enter